# Passing user created x,y coordinates as input feature to identity task using ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, modelbuilder, feature-set

Is there a way to pass user created x,y coordinates as input feature to the identity task?

I don't want to choose a table with x,y fields nor a feature class.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use a Feature Set which is described in the Online Help: [A quick tour of using Feature Set and Record Set](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//002w00000023000000) .

> Feature sets allow features to be entered interactively and
>   immediately used as input to a model or script.